# Swap the characters, Haskell

Tags: haskell

If str = "abcdpqrs", then we have to swap the characters at position {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)} as L = 8. So the answer will be "badcqpsr".

My algorithm work with problems:

Input is:

```
2
abcdpqrs
az
```

My output is:

```
"2"
"badcqpsr"
"za"
```

First input line is a number of test cases to follow. I want to skip this number. How I can do it? And how I can remove brackets?

My code:

```
rev (a : b : xs) = b : a : rev xs
rev xs = xs

main = do
    l <- getLine
    print (rev l)
    main
```

Comment: One *really* simple way: make `main` grab the first line, then call `main'` to handle the rest.

Comment: Is your input a fixed number of lines (3)?

Comment: hi @Jefffrey, not fixed

Comment: `import Control.Monad; main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM n $ getLine >>= putStrLn . rev`

Comment: @pertpoert then do you want to skip all numbers or just the first line?

Comment: @Jefffrey only in first line

Comment: @user3237465 thank you so much! Please make answer

Comment: `rev = foldl (flip (:)) []`, you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Control.Monad

main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM_ n $ getLine >>= putStrLn . rev
```

I.e. read the first line as a number `n` and then execute the action `getLine >>= putStrLn . rev` `n` times.